# .Net Core Automatically update User information after an appointment is set

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core, .net-6.0

I'm trying to figure out how I can select an appointment, when the time comes my system can automatically update the user's information.
At the moment I have no idea or any information on whether it is possible to have them work automatically. Here's what I'm trying to implement:

```
public class User 
{
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? changeStatusDate { get; set; }
}
if changeStatusDate = DateTime.Now
Status = StatusChange      //Status will be update and save to the Database
```

Example: I have a **changeStatusDate = 12/30/2022**

If **changeStatusDate = DateTime.Now**

User Status will be converted from *true* to *false*

I've tried searching but haven't found anything similar to what I'm doing.
Thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using properties set.

```
private DateTimeOffset? ChangeStatusDate;
public bool Status { get; set; }
public DateTimeOffset? changeStatusDate
{
    get { return ChangeStatusDate; }
    set
    {
        if (value == DateTime.Now)
        {
            Status = false;
        }
        ChangeStatusDate = value;
    } 
}
```

I understand your problem, so you are setting the property to `DateTime.Now` and when its value is exactly equal to it, it should set the `Status` to `false`. so you can't compare directly with DateTime.Now because every time it is different from other times. so you have to store that value somewhere and use it for comparison. in the below example, I have declared a class member, you can declare according to your requirement.

Here is the complete code.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static DateTime _dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
    public class User
    {
        private DateTimeOffset? ChangeStatusDate; // field
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? changeStatusDate
        {
            get { return ChangeStatusDate; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _dateTimeNow)
                {
                    Status = false;
                }
                ChangeStatusDate = value;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            User user = new User();
            user.Status = true;
            user.changeStatusDate = _dateTimeNow;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried and Status didn't change

Comment: I am using .Net Core API. Should I do it right at the User Model or on my API?

Comment: when are you creating 'User ' class object and setting `changeStatusDate ` ? I will be hard to tell without understanding the user case

Comment: I have a 'User' class that includes credentials and have implemented basic APIs like Login Logout.
I'm trying to set an appointment when it's time for the `UserStatus` to change automatically.
It will cause the User to not be able to login to the system anymore. I intend to create a `changeStatusDate` to compare with DateTime.Now to change User Status

Comment: @HuyNguyen is still not clear. But I gave you clear directions to solve the asked question. if you have more questions you can ask a new question. On StackOverflow, we are not here to provide you complete working project

Comment: @HuyNguyen Please accept the answer if it has solved your asked problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your query correctly, why don't you implement the changedStatusDate as full property and on the setter put the logic and set the status accordingly? Something like:

```
public class User 
{
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    private DateTimeOffset? changeStatusDate 
    public DateTimeOffset? ChangeStatusDate 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return changeStatusDate;
            } 
        set 
        { 
            changeStatusDate = value;
            if (changeStatusDate = DateTime.Now)
                Status =StatusChange;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried and Status didn't change

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not understanding your requirement. Please see this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TLDEFH) showing the code working. And @vivek code is also solid.

Comment: Well, maybe I wasn't really clear and knew what to choose for the question. After continuously researching, I came to **HangFire** to apply for my purposes. Thank you for the help